# assert on network payload request in cypress

Tags: testing, automation, cypress

Im working on validating network payload request using cypress, I need to assert that property include an array with dynamically changing values as in the following example, I figured how to validate when there is only one array item that is not changing ["code 12332"],

expect(req.body.food.dogowner).to.be.instanceOf(Array)
expect(req.body.food.dogowner[0]).to.eq("code 12332")

but how do I do that if the property array keeps changing every time a user adds an item and the number of items added to the array git bigger (say 200 or more)

{
dogname :"time",
"dogact" :"some"
"dogcolor" :"something",

food:{
"foodone" :"chicken",
"foodtwo":"cheese",
}
**dogowner :["code 12332" , "code 5445", " code 4555", "code 5554].......................................],**

}

every time you check the request the code value array change and more codes are added to the payload array?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the value of the entire array, but just that it has a specific value, you could use [Chai's include method.](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_include)

```js
expect(req.body.food.dogowner).to.be.instanceOf(Array) 
expect(req.body.food.dogowner).to.include("code 12332")
```